# Real difference between AsyncTask and Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, difference, asynctaskloader

I have been reading Android documentation ([AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#)) and [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#androidbackground) about this matter, but I have doubts yet.

For example, I want to send a message from an Android app to a server. And I would like this process to be responsive. What should I use?

I have seen examples where they create a new `Thread` for not block UI, but this way we don't have the progress of process, also you have to process the response within the `Thread` because the `run()` method doesn't returning anything.

`AsyncTask` seems better option than `Thread`, but I don't know what are the consequences of using an `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please read this blog

http://crazyaboutandroid.blogspot.in/2011/12/difference-between-android.html

and Details are:

**Difference between Android Service,Thread,IntentService and AsyncTask**

***When to use ?***

*Service*

```
   Task with no UI, but shouldn't be too long. Use threads within service for long tasks.
```

*Thread*

```
- Long task in general.

- For tasks in parallel use Multiple threads (traditional mechanisms)
```

**AsyncTask**

```
- Small task having to communicate with main thread.

- For tasks in parallel use multiple instances OR Executor
```

Comment: Where did you get that `AsyncTask` is for small tasks and `Thread` is for long tasks? Why shouldn't a person use `AsyncTask` for long tasks?

Comment: @BugsHappen Kindly check the following link and you will come to know why AsyncTask is recommended for small task.

Comment: Which link are you referring to?

Comment: @BugsHappen That is a very good question, technically there is no difference between an async task and a thread, only difference is that the async task can update the UI through its call back methods. So there should be no difference between an async task and a thread in terms of the length of operations that should be performed in them.

Comment: Dead link, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180102150725/http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html) for the blog table

Answer (score 21):

All other answers here are not complete, there is a big difference between AsyncTask and Thread, i.e.

Thread can be triggered from any thread, main(UI) or background; but AsyncTask must be triggered from main thread.

Also on lower API of Android(not sure, maybe API level < 11), one instance of AsyncTask can be executed only once.

For more information read [Difference between Android Service, Thread, IntentService and AsyncTask](http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html)

In general

**Thread**

- Long task in general.
- For tasks in parallel use Multiple threads (traditional mechanisms)

**AsyncTask**

- Small task having to communicate with main thread.
- For tasks in parallel use multiple instances OR Executor

Comment: Why should only short tasks be run in the AsyncTask? Since how the thread and async task operates are similar manner?

Answer (score 4):

in general using of 2 this features are equivalent, but AsyncTask is more simple in terms of integration with GUI

Comment: However the android documentation says 'AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)'

Comment: yeas, because of you work with GUI and user dont want to wait for a long period of time :)

Comment: But AsynTask will run like an independent thread. His work shouldn't affect to main thread (GUI). Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes, you have 2 points to synchonize: onreexecute and onpostexecute

Answer (score 4):

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

You can control its own functions

> doInBackground(Params... params),
>   onCancelled(),
>   onPostExecute(Result result),
>   onPreExecute(),
>   nProgressUpdate(Progress... values),
>   publishProgress(Progress... values)

Answer (score 4):

- I would prefer to Use **Async Task** as it will let you know when the
  `background process` gets **started and over** and when can I `parse`
  the response.
- **Async** has methods like `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` which will allow us to do tasks before and after calling the background
  tasks.

Answer (score 3):

`AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread.` - from [Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

The thing is - AsyncTask is a special kind of Thread - one which is a GUI thread, it works in the background and also let's you do something with the GUI - it is basically "pre-programmed" for you with functions `onPreExecute(), do inBackground(), onPostExecute()`.

In order to make `Thread` work that way, you have to write a loooot of code.

Comment: loooot of code isn't needed.. Using handlers is very basic